# Maven on eclipse creates undeletable target folder

Tags: windows-10, eclipse, maven

Its always a random Folder inside the target that is not only undeletable but also not accessible. When i try to access it with the explorer it says "access denied". It is also not possible to grant me access via the security settings of that folder (even with admin rights). In the advanced Security Settings it says that the current Owner cant be displayed. When i click on the change or advance Button with the Admin Symbol it always leads to a page where it just says smth like this: "You are not allowed to view or adjust the ownership settings.
(im using a german windows btw. so some translations may be not accurate)

BUT: after a reboot everything is fine and i can delete the target folder. I can then execute a couple of maven targets via cli without any problems (could be a coincidence) until i open eclipse. after a couple of minutes (or maven target runs) the problem repeats...

very frustrating... thanks in advance

edit:
the problem is definitely eclipse, which keeps a active handle on the folder. (It didnt notice at first because sometimes when i close eclipse it becomes a backgroundprocess and the handle is still active)

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/tananaev/traccar/issues/1210. Finally he wrote: I install clean Windows 8.1 again. Start Eclipse with normal privileges. All OK.

Comment: installing windows again seems a little bit to radical to me. at leas for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with the open filehandle seems to be a bug in terminal+ (a terminal replacement which is part of the Webclipse plugin). When executing a maven target within that terminal, theres a big chance the filehandle is not removed after the target is finished. so just stop using terminal+. no biggie for me.